# How to calculate 0.5 million into thousands?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm no smarter than a 5yr old when it comes to maths (hence I'm here asking for help) so if you could keep that in mind when explaining the answer to me please :-)

So as the title suggests, I have a value: `0.5` million and I want to be able to represent it in thousands (so `500` thousand).

How do I do this (i.e. what's the formula)?

Comment: $1 \text{ million} = 1000 \text{ thousands}$. Multiply both sides by $\dfrac 12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_{thousand}=millions  \ * 1000 $ so if u get 0.7 millions u will get $x_{thousand}=0.7 * 1000 = 700 $

Answer (score 0):

There are thousand $1000$s per $1$ million. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\require{cancel}0.5\text{ million} &= 0.5\text{ million }\times\frac{1000\text{ thousand}}{1\text{ million}}\\ &= 0.5\cancel{\text{ million }}\times\frac{1000\text{ thousand}}{\cancel{1\text{ million}}}\\
&=0.5\times1000\text{ thousand}\\
&= 500\text{ thousand}.
\end{aligned}
$$

In general
$$N \text{ million} = 1000\times N\text{ thousand.}$$